# Does anyone have the layout of the Google Pixel 3 xl?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-emulator, google-pixel

Inadvertently replace the emulator layout of the google pixel 3 xl and I can no longer find it anywhere, is the file found in this path: C:\Users\your_user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\skins\pixel_3_xl

[image]

already look it all over Google and I can't find it someone with a good heart to pass it to me please :c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I opened it in notepad++:

```
parts {
  device {
    display {
      width 1440
      height 2960
      x 0
      y 0
    }
  }
  portrait {
    background {
      image port_back.webp
    }
    foreground {
      mask round_corners.webp
      cutout emu01
    }
    onion {
      image port_fore.webp
    }
  }
}
layouts {
  portrait {
    width 1684
    height 3246
    event EV_SW:0:1
    part1 {
      name portrait
      x 0
      y 0
    }
    part2 {
      name device
      x 126
      y 72
    }
  }
}
```